# What published adventures are there that focus on nanotech?

Tags: system-agnostic, published-adventures

**I'm looking for some fresh ideas for adventures centered on nanotech** and I don't care about what system they come from.   I plan to adapt them for my own use so I may or may not use the system/setting they are written for.  Please only suggest them if you have them or have played them.  The main thing is that they are innovative.  It is also important that I can obtain them legally as I like to support the creators.  Out of print is ok so long as it is not a "collector" item.

I am hoping to leverage the massive knowledge and experience here as my own searches have not yielded much fruit.  So please check out your shelf or closet or underground vault of books and let me know of any gems you've seen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Eclipse Phase](http://eclipsephase.com/) contains a lot of story seeds using nanotechs as either McGuffin, active obstacles, or as setting enhancer.  All the books are released under the [CC](http://creativecommons.org/) and there is a [torrent](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=eclipse+phase+torrent) where you can get them from. [How does, or how might, nanotechnology work?](http://eclipsephase.com/how-does-or-how-might-nanotechnology-work) and [Who needs nanotech?](http://eclipsephase.com/who-needs-nanotech) should give you an idea of how nanotech is used in the game.